# FOREACH and WHILE not displaying results correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get data from one sql table, and then create a drop down list of data from another table.

The FOREACH correctly displays all the entries, but the WHILE is only populating the drop down once. I want it to be generated in the first column of all entries from the FOREACH return.

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect ot MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
// get values from SQL server
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tasks order by Period, Sort ASC";
    $sql_period = "SELECT * FROM Lists";
    $result_period = $con->query($sql_period);
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
/* <table> creation code goes here */
    foreach ($data as $row) {
?>
        <TD>
        <select name="Period" ID="<?PHP echo $row["ID"]; ?>">
<?PHP
// Loop all valid List periods and build select list
        while($row_period = $result_period->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row["Period"] == $row_period["ID"]) {
                echo '<option value=' . $row_period["Period"] . ' Selected="Selected">' .  $row_period["Period"] . '</option>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<option value=' . $row_period["Period"] . '>' . $row_period["Period"] . '</option>';
            }
        }
?>
        </select></TD>
<?PHP
// display results of Tasks
        echo "<TD>" . $row["Task"] . "</TD><TD ALIGN=right>" . $row["Sort"] . "</TD></TR>";
    }
```

I used to be able to do this easily in mysql WHILE loops, but mysqli is new to me.
I have been playing with this for 2 days, different variations and can't get it to work. Help gratefully appreciated.

[page results][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvZ1n.png

Comment: you need to use foreach for the **inner** loop

Comment: perfect, thanks. This was so much easier before mysqli

Comment: There is **absolutely** no difference. You would have the same problem as well